# Refreshing Oracle database tables after initial copy is made

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a production and development database (on different systems of course).  Many months ago, I copied the production database to the development system.  I used exp/imp at the time.  Since then there has been quite a few changes in the production database I would like to copy down to the development database.  I'd rather not wipe out the development database and start over because of data I've had to add to the development database.

My original thought was to use MERGE INTO to copy the new records.  But this apparently requires me to do this for tables, and list all fields of all tables.  We're talking hundreds of tables and thousands of fields here.  Not a pretty solution.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Whenever I feel overwhelmed by the number of tables or columns, I always resort to generating these queries from a view like `all_tab_columns`. Take a day to write the query that will generate these hundreds of `MERGE` queries for you and then you can reuse them to refresh as often as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the TABLE_EXISTS parameter of impdp to append the new data to the existing tables?  Duplicate keys will error off but the rest of the data should still import.  The results will be a bit messy.  Prior to running TRUNCATE any tables in test where you can just bring the entire production table.  Disable FK.  Re-enable after import.
- -
Another option create a database link and generate INSERT/SELECT into all tables where data not in existing test table.  You probably also want to disable FK prior to running and re-enable when done.